# In what sense is the co-presheaf $C^\infty(X)$ an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

I am following this [page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/C%5E%E2%88%9E-ring) on ncatlab for $C^\infty$-algebras

There are two definitions given for $C^\infty(X)$ where $X$ is a smooth manifold. The first is $C^\infty(X, \mathbb{R})$ which inherits a ring structure from $\{+, \cdot\}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ so in a sense could be considered an algebra. But the place in which $C^\infty(X)$ is introduced as an algebra, it is defined (3.5) to be a co-presheaf functor $C^\infty(X) =: \text{Hom}_\text{Diff}(X, -): \text{CartSp} \rightarrow \text{Set}$ and this is what is assumed (in definition 3.6) to have a ring structure. What is this structure?

Comment: I remember from a dark past that certain representable functors give rise to commutative Hopf algebra structures. Perhaps something similar is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I think the page is being fairly clear: if you define $C^{\infty}(X)$ as the functor $F=\operatorname{Hom_{Diff}}(X,-)$, then you recover the usual ring $C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})$ as $F(\mathbb{R})$, and the product $C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})\times C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})\to C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is the image under $F$ of the product map $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. I don't see how this comes up in definition 3.6 though.

But the idea is that a "smooth algebra" in this sense is not really an algebra. With this definition, $C^{\infty}(X)$ is not a "set endowed with algebra operations", but a whole functor, and the usual algebra of smooth functions $C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})$ with its usual operations is just one incarnation of this object (which corresponds to applying the functor to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: In 3.6 it comes up in a couple of places. The functor $U$ is said to be taking a $C^\infty$ algebra to its underlying ring, but what would that be for $C^\infty(X)$? Also it speaks directly of the ideal of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is this just abusing the notation and omitting the $X$? That would mean that the real $C^\infty$ algebra is $C^\infty(X, \mathbb{R^n})$ which is at least a ring so has an ideal, and its underlying ring would be $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Or is $U: C^\infty(X) \mapsto C^\infty(X, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $U$ takes a $C^\infty$-ring $A$ to $A(\mathbb R)$, seen as an ordinary ring. $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is used in abuse of notation, as is possibly confusing but explained on the page, as a synonym for $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)(\mathbb R).$